# Width/height of the plot area in a dimple.chart

Tags: dimple.js

after creating a new dimple.chart there are available chart.x and chart.y as defined in
https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart
On the other hand the values for chart.width and chart.height are 0.
Is there any other way to find the with/height of the plot area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `chart._widthPixels()` and `chart._heightPixels()` they aren't part of the public API but are used extensively internally for the plot size.